# Put string start with "@" in android resources

Tags: android, string, resources

I need add string starts with "@" in android resources, but take error:

> No resource type specified (at 'str1' with value '@%s test').

My string is:

```
<string name="str1" formatted="false">@%s test</string>
```

How I must encode "@" to place it in string resources?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can just escape it `\@`

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the `@` sign with `\`. Additionally, you should reference the arguments using their position:

```
<string name="str1" formatted="false">\@%1$s test</string>
```

Comment: "Works fine" does not mean "is correct"... in that case, when you have a single argument, no worries, but when you have more, translators might use them in different order. It is good practise to always use positionned arguments to remain consistent & avoid forgetting it when important